# Where to use @NamedQueries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using @NamedQueries but not sure what is the best way to use it.

1. Use it above entity class
2. Use it above DAO class
3. Create One NamedQueriesFactory class which will have centralized named queries for all Entity
4. Any other better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i good way would be to put all of them in an xml file which is used a lot. this externalizes your queries and gives you the freedom of just sending over this xml file to some DBA for easier analysis later on.

Comment: in your persistence unit xml file you can then include them by
    <mapping-file>META-INF/example_orm.xml</mapping-file>

Answer (score 1):

2 (Dao) and 3 (factory class) are not real options, assuming that those are not also entities, because according [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedQueries.html):

> The NamedQueries annotation can be applied to an entity or mapped
>   superclass.

That leaves as with 1 (entity) and 4 (mapped superclass). I would locate queries by return type and/or main entity accessed in query. Because mapped superclass cannot be returned from the JPQL queries, answer would be 1 (entity).